# Can I use my own service to build an imodel display program?

Tags: imodeljs

Parse the imodel file with nodejs, build the display system on the intranet.

Does imodel provide such capabilities?

Comment: Can you show your code with more specific details?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could use [IModelDb.exportGraphics](https://imodeljs.github.io/iModelJs-docs-output/reference/imodeljs-backend/imodels/imodeldb/exportgraphics/) to output to another display system.

Unless you have a compelling reason to use another display system, it's much easier to use the built-in one because it's already designed to scale to very large models.